# Django validation in model clean() with M2M fields can not work on creation

Tags: python, django

How do you handle model validation that implies M2M fields?

For example,

```
class Object1
    objects_2 = models.ManyToManyField(Object2)

    def clean():
        # any operation implying objects_2 field.
        # for example: if self.objects_2.exists() ...
```

This will work for un **update**, but at object **creation**, I will encounter this error: `"<Object1>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.`.

I understand this error, but how would you do to make a proper validation in that case?

My current workaround is to remove the `objects_2` field from the form if the user is creating an Object1 instance, and force the user to edit the Object1 instance to change that field.
Awful right?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can override the form's clean and access `cleaned_data['objects_2']`

Comment: Would you completely remove the model's clean to use the form's clean only?

Comment: If you have to override the form anyway, I think I would. You have access to the model instance via `form.instance` as well, but you know nothing about the form in the model's `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

[django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster) permits working with related models before you have saved them to the database. It has a `ParentalManyToManyField` that offers some advantages for many-to-many relationships, but as it says in the README, the child objects (Object2 instances) must exist in the database before you start to add them to Object1.

Instead you can use django-modelcluster's `ParentalKey` relationship, and manually populate the through table:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey


class Object2(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ObjectThroughModel(models.Model):
    object_1 = ParentalKey('Object1', related_name='through_model')
    object_2 = ParentalKey('Object2', related_name='through_model')


class Object1(ClusterableModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def clean(self):
        for through_object in self.through_model.all():
            if self.name in through_object.object_2.name:
                raise ValidationError("Object 2 name cannot contain object 1's name")
```

This allows you to do:

```
>>> o1 = Object1(name='hi')
>>> o1.through_model.add(ObjectThroughModel(object_2=Object2(name='hi2')))
>>> o1.clean()
ValidationError: ["Object 2 name cannot contain object 1's name"]
```